# Using Telerik radDropDownList

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, telerik

i have `Winforms` application and i want to use `Telerik` controllers instead of `Winforms` controllers.

My application have `Combobox` that get all my machine `Network adapters`:

```
private NetworkAdapter selectedAdapter = null;
ComboBox comboBoxAdapter;
```

My machine adapters is type of `NetworkAdapter`.
after my application start i get all the adapters:

```
IEnumerable<NetworkAdapter> res = NetworkAdapter.getAll();
```

Insert all the adapters into my `Combobox`:

```
 this.ActiveControl = comboBoxAdapter;
 comboBoxAdapter.Items.AddRange(res.ToArray());
```

And `comboBoxAdapter_SelectedIndexChanged`:

```
private void comboBoxAdapter_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
    selectedAdapter = cmb.SelectedItem as NetworkAdapter;
}
```

Now i added `Telerik radDropDownList`
Because `Telerik radDropDownList` AddRange received only `string` i put all my `NetworkAdapter` inside `List<string>`:

```
List<string> addList = new List<string>();

foreach (NetworkAdapter add in NetworkAdapter.getAll())
    addList.Add(add.Description);

radDropDownList1.Items.AddRange(addList);
```

And i have this issue:

This is my `radDropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged`:

```
private void radDropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.Data.PositionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
    selectedAdapter = cmb.SelectedItem as NetworkAdapter;
}
```

And for some reason `selectedAdapter`  is allways `null`

Answer (score 0):

just wondering why are your still using ComboBox to cast sender (on your last menthod)

```
private void radDropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.Data.PositionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
    selectedAdapter = cmb.SelectedItem as NetworkAdapter;
}
```

i think it should be

```
private void radDropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.Data.PositionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var cmb = sender as RadDropDownList;
    selectedAdapter = cmb.SelectedItem as NetworkAdapter;
}
```

though i am not sure.